Error on transaction execute on my web site
When I execute my code on my ASP.NET website, I get this error:

Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

My stored procedure contains this code:
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [LIBERA_ABATIMENTOS_GRADE]

    DECLARE @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO INT

    DECLARE SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS CURSOR FOR
        SELECT G.GRD_HORA, G.GRD_VOLHOR
        FROM dbo.GradeProgramacao G WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE G.EMP_CODIGO = @INP_EMP_CODIGO
          AND G.BAS_CODIGO = @INP_BAS_CODIGO
          AND G.CLI_CODIGO = @INP_CLI_CODIGO
          AND G.GRD_DATA = CONVERT(DATE, @INP_GRD_DATA_ANT)
          AND G.GRD_HORA > CONVERT(TIME, @INP_GRD_DATA_ANT)
                
    OPEN SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS

    FETCH NEXT FROM SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS INTO @F_GRD_HORA, @F_GRD_VOLHOR

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO = ISNULL(@V_VOL_GRD_VOLHOR - @F_GRD_VOLHOR, 0)

        IF @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO < 0
            SET @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO = 0

        IF @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO > 0 AND @F_GRD_VOLHOR < @V_VOL_GRD_VOLHOR
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.GradeProgramacao
            SET GRD_VOLHOR = @F_GRD_VOLHOR + @V_VOLUME_NECESSARIO
            WHERE EMP_CODIGO = @INP_EMP_CODIGO
              AND BAS_CODIGO = @INP_BAS_CODIGO
              AND CLI_CODIGO = @INP_CLI_CODIGO
              AND GRD_DATA = CONVERT(DATE, @INP_GRD_DATA_ANT)
              AND GRD_HORA = @F_GRD_HORA
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS INTO @F_GRD_HORA, @F_GRD_VOLHOR
    END

    CLOSE SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS
    DEALLOCATE SELECAO_HORARIOS__VOLUME_HORA_ABATIDOS

    -- Executing another stored procedure within the same transaction
    EXEC dbo.CheckVolumeExceeded
        @INP_EMP_CODIGO = @INP_EMP_CODIGO,
        @INP_BAS_CODIGO = @INP_BAS_CODIGO,
        @INP_CLI_CODIGO = @INP_CLI_CODIGO,
        @INP_GRD_DATLAN = @V_GRD_DATA_NOV,
        @INP_GRD_HORA = @V_GRD_HORA_NOV,
        @INP_VOLUME_AGENDAMENTO = @V_FOP_QUANTI,
        @OUT_CODERR = @V_CODERR OUTPUT,
        @OUT_MENERR = @V_MENERR OUTPUT

    IF @V_CODERR IS NULL SET @V_CODERR = 0

    IF @V_CODERR > 0 AND @V_CODERR < 99
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [LIBERA_ABATIMENTOS_GRADE]
        SELECT @OUT_CODERR = 1, @OUT_MENERR = @V_MENERR
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION [LIBERA_ABATIMENTOS_GRADE]
    END

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    SELECT @OUT_CODERR = 1, @OUT_MENERR = 'Operation Cancelled! An internal error occurred. Please contact support.'
END CATCH


        DROP PROCEDURE SP_CHECK_VOLUME_EXCEED_BASE_CONGENERE
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CHECK_VOLUME_EXCEED_BASE_CONGENERE
(
@INP_EMP_CODE               INTEGER     =   0       ,
@INP_BAS_CODE               INTEGER     =   0       ,
@INP_CLI_CODE               INTEGER     =   0       ,
@INP_GRD_DATE               DATE        =   ''      ,
@INP_GRD_TIME               TIME        =   ''      ,
@INP_SCHEDULED_VOLUME           FLOAT       =   0       ,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@OUT_BASE_AVAILABLE_VOLUME      FLOAT       =   0   OUTPUT  ,
@OUT_CONGENERE_AVAILABLE_VOLUME FLOAT       =   0   OUTPUT  ,
@OUT_ALLOWED_EXCESS         CHAR(001)   =   'N' OUTPUT  ,
@OUT_REMAINING_EXCESS_VOLUME        FLOAT       =   0   OUTPUT  ,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@OUT_ERR_CODE               INTEGER     =   0   OUTPUT  ,
@OUT_ERR_MSG                VARCHAR(255)    =   ''  OUTPUT
)
WITH
ENCRYPTION
AS
DECLARE
@V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME        FLOAT   ,
@V_BASE_HOURLY_AVAILABLE_VOLUME         FLOAT   ,
@V_BASE_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME               FLOAT   ,
@V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_VOLUME         FLOAT   ,
@V_LAST_DAILY_LOADING_TIME              TIME    ,
@V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME          FLOAT   ,
@V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED       FLOAT   ,
@V_POST_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME     FLOAT   ,
@V_LAST_TRIP                    VARCHAR(001)

    ---------------------------------------------------
    SET @OUT_ALLOWED_EXCESS =   'N' 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHECK_IF_LAST_LOADING_OF_DAY:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT  TOP 1
        @V_LAST_DAILY_LOADING_TIME  =   LZ_TABLE.GRD_TIME   ,
        @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME  =   ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_HOUR_VOLUME),0) - (ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_PROGRAMMED),0) + ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_CONFIRMED),0)),
        @V_LAST_TRIP            =   LZ_TABLE.LAST_TRIP
    FROM    LZ_TABLE    WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   LZ_TABLE.EMP_CODE   =   @INP_EMP_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.BAS_CODE   =   @INP_BAS_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.CLI_CODE   =   @INP_CLI_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.GRD_DATE   =   @INP_GRD_DATE    
    GROUP   BY
        LZ_TABLE.GRD_TIME   ,
        LZ_TABLE.LAST_TRIP  
    ORDER   BY
        LZ_TABLE.GRD_TIME DESC
    
    IF  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME  IS  NULL    SELECT  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME  =   0   
    
    
    IF  @V_LAST_DAILY_LOADING_TIME  =   @INP_GRD_TIME   
    BEGIN
            IF  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME  >   0   AND @V_LAST_TRIP    =   'N'
        BEGIN       
                SELECT  @OUT_ERR_CODE   =   9001    ,
                @OUT_ERR_MSG    =   'Unlimited Volume Available!'
                    
            GOTO    DO_NOTHING  
        END
        
        SELECT  @OUT_ERR_CODE   =   2   ,   
            @OUT_ERR_MSG    =   'Error Code.6098 - Operation Cancelled! Last Trip Flag Already Marked, No Further Scheduling Possible.'             

        GOTO    DO_NOTHING      
    
    END 
        

        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------       
CHECK_IF_CONGENERE_HOUR_VOLUME_AVAILABLE_IS_ZERO:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    --------------------------------------------------
    SELECT  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED   =   0
    
    SELECT  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED   =   ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_HOUR_VOLUME),0) - (ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_PROGRAMMED),0) + ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_CONFIRMED),0))  
    FROM    LZ_TABLE        WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   LZ_TABLE.EMP_CODE   =   @INP_EMP_CODE   AND
            LZ_TABLE.BAS_CODE   =   @INP_BAS_CODE   AND
            LZ_TABLE.CLI_CODE   =   @INP_CLI_CODE   AND
            LZ_TABLE.GRD_DATE   =   @INP_GRD_DATE   AND
            LZ_TABLE.GRD_TIME   =   @INP_GRD_TIME

    IF  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED   IS  NULL    SET @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED   =   0
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF  @V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED   <=  0
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @OUT_ERR_CODE   =   2   ,   
                @OUT_ERR_MSG    =   'Error Code.6096 - Operation Cancelled! No Available Volume for Congenere Scheduling at Date/Time: ['
                            + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@INP_GRD_DATE,103) + ' ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@INP_GRD_TIME),05) +']' + CHAR(13) + 
                            'and Excess Volume Not Allowed in this Case.'   +   CHAR(13)    +
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CAST(@V_CONGENERE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME_ZEROED AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
                        


        GOTO    DO_NOTHING          
    END     
        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHECK_CONGENERE_HOUR_VOLUME_AVAILABLE:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET @V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME    =   0
    
    SELECT  @V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME    =   ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_HOUR_VOLUME),0) - (ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_PROGRAMMED),0) + ISNULL(SUM(LZ_TABLE.GRD_CONFIRMED),0)) 
    FROM    LZ_TABLE    WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   LZ_TABLE.EMP_CODE   =   @INP_EMP_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.BAS_CODE   =   @INP_BAS_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.CLI_CODE   =   @INP_CLI_CODE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.GRD_DATE   =   @INP_GRD_DATE   AND
        LZ_TABLE.GRD_TIME   =   @INP_GRD_TIME   
        
        
    IF  @V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME IS NULL    SET @V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME    =   0   
        
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VOLUME_WITHIN_ALLOWED_HOUR_LIMIT:
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF  @INP_SCHEDULED_VOLUME       <=  @V_CONGENERE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_HOUR_VOLUME    
    BEGIN
        SET @OUT_ERR_CODE   =   0
        GOTO    DO_NOTHING  
    END
    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--CHECK_BASE_DAILY_AVAILABLE_VOLUME:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--  SET @V_BASE_AVAILABLE_DAILY_VOLUME  =   0

--  SELECT  @V_BASE_AVAILABLE_DAILY_VOLUME  =   ISNULL(LZ_TABLE.GRD_DAILY_VOLUME,0) - (ISNULL(LZ_TABLE.GRD_PROGRAMMED,0) + ISNULL(LZ_TABLE.GRD_CONFIRMED,0))
--  FROM    LZ_TABLE    WITH(NOLOCK)
--  WHERE   LZ_TABLE.EMP_CODE   =   @INP_EMP_CODE   AND
--      LZ_TABLE.BAS_CODE   =   @INP_BAS_CODE   AND
--      LZ_TABLE.GRD_DATE   =   @INP_GRD_DATE   
        
--  IF  @V_BASE_AVAILABLE_DAILY_VOLUME IS NULL  SET @V_BASE_AVAILABLE_DAILY_VOLUME  =   0   
        
--  IF  @V_BASE_AVAILABLE_DAILY_VOLUME  <=  0
--  BEGIN
--      SELECT  @OUT_ERR_CODE   =   1   ,   
--          @OUT_ERR_MSG    =   'Error Code.5070 - Operation Cancelled! No Available Base Volume on [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@INP_GRD_DATE,103) + '] for Excess Volume Consumption.'
            
--      GOTO    DO_NOTHING          
--  END 
    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--CHECK_BASE_HOUR_AVAILABLE_VOLUME:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET @V_BASE_HOURLY_AVAILABLE_VOLUME =   0

    SELECT  @V_BASE_HOURLY_AVAILABLE_VOLUME =   ISNULL(LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_HOUR_VOLUME,0) - ((ISNULL(LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_PROGRAMMED,0)) + (ISNULL(LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_CONFIRMED,0)) + (ISNULL(LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_IDLE_USE,0)))
    FROM    LZ_HOUR_TABLE   WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   LZ_HOUR_TABLE.EMP_CODE  =   @INP_EMP_CODE   AND
        LZ_HOUR_TABLE.BAS_CODE  =   @INP_BAS_CODE   AND
        LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_DATE  =   @INP_GRD_DATE   AND
        LZ_HOUR_TABLE.GRD_HOUR  =   @INP_GRD_TIME   

I tried to remove an exec, and it works, but I need the exec after the update inside of the transaction.

it's work when i put this code for verify my transaction:
if @@transcount = 0 begin transaction
and same thing for rollback and commit

Are you actually still using sql server 2008r2? It is long past time to sort out an upgrade path. That version has been fully unsupported for a few years now.

Does your calc routine also have transactions? If so, that is the issue. Nested transactions make logical sense but they simply don't work in sql server the way you might think.

no, in calc routine is another procedure, where i do perform my calcs, withou transactions.
I'm using Sql server 2008 r2 on my job, i can not change this

If outputcode > 0 then you rollback but then attempt to commit - how is that supposed to work?

Time to convince the decision makers that an upgrade is beyond critical. At this point it is like using Windows2008 and saying you can't possibly to an upgrade to a supported OS.

To paraphrase your code it is this. Begin transaction, rollback transaction, commit transaction.

You need to include your table update and exec statement, we need to see you exact code to help

@SeanLange I saw an article yesterday which indicates that something like 30% of production SQL server instances are out of support

@DaleK that is horrifying. Those same companies would never use an out of date OS or version of software. I just don't get why so many places just don't seem to care about the system that stores the lifeblood of their entire business.

@sean My bad, only 20% now but soon to be 30 https://www.theregister.com/2024/06/17/outdated_sql_server/

I put real code edited on this question

Well the problem still exists. begin transaction, rollback transaction, commit transaction.

Not part of your question but why a cursor for updates? That should be set based. Also...https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix and https://thwack.solarwinds.com/groups/data-driven/b/blog/posts/bad-habits-putting-nolock-everywhere

In fact, in the company where I work we use cursors for everything, since the beginning, it was in 1995 :), I never used cursors before working at the company, it's very curious.

actually, i work with legacy softwares, that's why this old way of using codes.
